# Inserir data e hora no mysql automaticamente?

Tags: mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

estou criando um sisteminha e gostaria de saber  tipo preencho o formulário abaixo e como faço pra inserir no mysql a hora e a data conforme está no sistema operacional .sem ter colocar um input data e hora no formulário .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basta você criar uma tabela com o campo data do tipo `TIMESTAMP`e com o valor pre-definido como `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Segue Exemplo sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `tabelateste` (
  `data` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Dessa forma, sempre que inserir um registro, nao precisará informar a data, e ela sera inserida com a data do sistema do servidor

Comment: Você poderia me fazer um favor , tem aqueles dados do formulários acima , tipo , numero da comanda, num da mesa , pedido de comida e bebida e quantidades , poderia me mostrar como criar as tabela juntos com a data e hora ? ficaria grato @localHost

Comment: sim , com o xampp

Comment: bem o nome do banco de dado é peixaria , os dados a serem inseridos são os da imagem acima , tipo , numero da comanda , vai vim automaticamente toda vez que eu abrir um novo formulário. tem o número da mesa, a refeição e a quantidade, a bebida e a quantidade.

Comment: Eu recomendo voce criar uma tabela pedido com {id_pedido,numero_comanda, numero_mesa} e outra tabela item_pedido{id_item, id_pedido, pedido, quantidade} .Isso seria a maneira mais simples, onde o id_pedido 'e sempre informado em cada item que vai ser informado na tabela item_pedido

Comment: então será essas duas novas e a tabela da data e hora é

Comment: @allanaraujo a tabela que tem a data seria a pedido , pois seria um pedido com as informaçoes do mesmo, ai na outra armazenaria os itens desse pedido

Comment: Ficou assim CREATE TABLE `peixaria`.`item_pedido` ( `id_item` INT NOT NULL , `id_pedido` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `pedido` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `quantidad` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `data` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , `algo` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id_item`)) ENGINE = MyISAM CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;  está certo ?

Comment: @allanaraujo acredito que sim, mas a quantidade poderia ser int ou double